# Optimizing react-slick carousel from creating too many DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-slick

I am struggling with a problem that I have too many DOM elements on my page. PageSpeed Insights
recommends to me to reduce it and shows me that my carousel is quite large.

I have like 150 elements there, I am showing 10 elements (small images) at once. 
I am wondering is there any option to reduce those elements in DOM structure?

The first thing which comes to my mind is to replace react-slick with a different library but didn't find anything that solves my problem, so the second thing is to implement it.

Thanks for any response.